# Como saltar al catch condicionalmente?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

En este try, `results` es undefined porque estoy recibiendo un error 500 del backend. Me surgen dos preguntas:

1- el error 500 o 400 no debería hacer saltar al catch automaticamente?

2- en el caso de que 1 sea falso (asi lo supongo, ya que no salta) como puedo saltar al catch si `results` es `null` o `undefined`?

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.BOOK_URL, {
      body: data,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    const results = json.data;

    console.log("RESULTS?? ", results);
    return res.status(200).json({
      data: {
        results,
      },
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
```

Comment: lo que buscas es que, cuando la variable res.status sea 400 o 500 se vaya al catch?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x exacto. Era mas facil copiarla en el chat gpt pero prefiero venir a molestar un rato acá 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás mezclando dos conceptos: un error en la ejecución del código y los estados de la respuesta HTTP.

Si haces una llamada HTTP a un servicio y obtienes (por ejemplo) un estado HTTP 404, Javascript considera que la llamada ha sido resuelta con **éxito**: Se ha obtenido una respuesta que cumple con el estándar y te da información (en este caso que el recurso que buscas no existe).

Del mismo modo, si recibes un HTTP 500, has obtenido exitosamente un mensaje que te indica que el servidor está teniendo problemas, pero no son **tus** problemas (como cliente).

¿Cuándo lanzará `fetch` un error/excepción? Por ejemplo si la URL no se puede resolver (el dominio no existe) o si la conexión está fallando (no hay conexión de red o el servidor no responde, provocando un error por timeout:

```js
async function test() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('www.goooooogle.com')
    console.log(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error', error.message)
  }
}

test()
```

Dicho de otro modo, si `fetch` puede generar un objeto `response`, no se lanzará un error, pero puedes preguntar si todo ha ido bien. Un ejemplo usando Star Wars API (swapi.dev), que es un servicio REST gratuito para hacer pruebas:

```js
async function test(data) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${data}`)
    if (response.ok) {
      let responseData=await response.json()
      console.log(responseData.name, responseData.gender)
    } else {
      console.log('No OK, estado', response.status)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error', error.message)
  }
}

test('people/200') // 404
test('people/1')   // 200, Luke Skywalker
```

Answer (score 2):

La API de `fetch` solo arroja un error si hay un error en la red. De lo contrario siempre devuelve un resultado con el código HTTP.

En la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) se lee:

> El objeto Promise devuelto desde fetch() no será rechazado con un estado de error HTTP incluso si la respuesta es un error HTTP 404 o 500. En cambio, este se resolverá normalmente (con un estado ok configurado a false), y este solo sera rechazado ante un fallo de red o si algo impidió completar la solicitud.

Para la pregunta 2, suelo usar una de 2 formas:

1. `try..catch` anidados, donde el `try..catch` externo es el del propio `fetch` para atrapar los errores de red, de acuerdo con el documento anterior. El `try..catch` interior es para implementar manejo de errores propios, donde yo mismo arrojo un error si encuentro un resultado 400 o 500. Esto ultimo se puede hacer con `if`, pero de esta forma me resulta más limpio.
2. Crear distintas clases de errores que extienden la clase `Error`. Al detectar un código de erorr en la respuesta HTTP, arrojo el error correspondiente. Luego el `catch` lo trata según corresponda.

Ejemplo:

```
class UnauthorizedError extends Error {
    constructor (message) {
        super(message);
        this.name = "UnauthorizedError";
    }
}

class UndefinedResponseError extends Error {
    constructor (message) {
        super(message);
        this.name = "UndefinedResponseError";
    }
}

try {
    const response = fetch();
    if (response.code === 401) {
        throw new UnauthorizedError("No identificado");
    }
    // ... get result
    if (result === undefined) {
        throw new UndefinedResponseError("Devuelve undefined");
    }
} catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof UnauthorizedError) {
        console.error("Error al autenticar:", err.message);
    } else if (err instanceof UndefinedResponseError) {
        console.error("El resultado es 'undefined':", err.messgae);    
    } else { // en este caso, se cumple "err instanceof TypeError"
        console.error("Error en la red");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

por lo general la parte del result status yo siempre la manejo con un if

```
if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    //hacer algo
} else{
   //manejar el error
}
```